# Use DotNetOpenAuth to authenticate for Google Drive SDK

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api, dotnetopenauth

I have used ASP.NET simple membership database with DotNetOpenOAuth to login to my ASP.NET MVC application. I want to use the same authentication credentials to authenticate for using Google Drive app. Namely, can I use AuthenticationResult object details to build IAuthenticator object for authenticating into my Google Drive app?

My aim is to use the already signed-in Google user for later authorizing to use my Google Drive App and not asking him/her again for credentials.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get authorized and authenticated to a Drive backend, you need to retrieve and persist and access token to append it to each request you make. The typical flow for a system that already implements an auth layer is:

- Authenticate user
- Connect your user to a Google Drive account by following the auth steps explained on [1].
- Persist the access token, refresh token for the user.
- Authenticate each request you're making on the behalf of the user with his/her access token.

[1] https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth

Comment: That's clear for me. But, I would like to use the built-in OAuth authentication for membership purposes of my application and then use the same authentication details e.g. e-mail to authorize a Google Drive app. Namely, in the ExternalLoginCallBack method of the AccountController the authentication is done through the following codeline `AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));` then I call `IAuthenticator authenticator = Utils.GetCredentials(null, null);` to initialize Drive App authorization

Comment: My question is how to use `Utils.GetCredentials` method to leverage authentication details provided earlier through `AuthenticationResult`.